# Why are list/comboboxes sometimes empty until form is refreshed?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am developing a Database in Access 2010, which multiple users access at once (separated frontend/backend). Now that more users are startin to use it, I have stumbled upon a pretty inconsistent problem:
Some users see empty Listboxes/Comboboxes until they close the current form and open it again, or press f5. This doesn't happen to all users, and it doesn't always happen (meaning a user sometimes has this problem and sometimes not).
I have managed to find out, that this only happens to controls that are filled using VBA -if I specify a query in the properties tab, it works normally.

Here is how I fill the controls:

```
Dim sQuery As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

sQuery = "SELECT ID, Name FROM Users WHERE ID <> 1"

Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset (sQuery)
Set listBox.Recordset = rs

Set rs = Nothing
```

While developing, this happened to me a few times and I could get around it using Me.Refresh or Me.Repaint (sometimes one worked, sometimes the other).

Personally I don't find it difficult to just press F5 when I see an emtpy list that should be filled, but as more users are using this, it is quite inconvenient for them.

So is such behaviour normal? Am I missing something when filling the controls? Could it be a problem of computer performance (as in the control is painted before it can be filled)?

Answer (score 0):

List boxes or combo boxes do not to refresh automatically. As you stated to do this programmatically use the Refresh method of the control.

This is by design so that the form is not constantly rerunning queries that are not necessary.

Your options are as far as I am aware:

Create a button next to a control that needs to be refreshed. Then in the click event of the button call the Refresh Method of the control.

Write code in the got focus event of the control to call the refresh method.

Set up the forms timer event to refresh the control at set intervals.

I think the button is the best approach as it gives the user a visual cue and the query is only run when absolutely necessary.

Note there is a subtle difference between using the refresh method of the control and form. When you use the refresh method of the form you are refreshing the forms record source not the listbox or ComboBox row source. For example:

```
Me.Requery ' this is refreshing form
Me.ListBox1.Requery 'this is refreshing a individual control
```

Comment: That workaround is unfortunately not exactly what I'm looking for, as I would like the user to see the records as soon as the form loads. I also found another interesting behaviour: if the listbox is emtpy when the form loads, the user can click on any other button located on the form and then the records show. I have also tried using SendKeys to simulate the press of the F5 button, but it did not work. But as it is so inconsistent among users, I suspect that it has something to do with their computers performance. Maybe access draws the form and needs too long to fill the control?

Comment: When the form loads everything should be up-to-date and displayed. What I was referring to is if the items in a row source of the listbox or ComboBox is changed in the underlying table after the form is opened then these changes will not automatically refresh.

Are all the tables local or are you pulling across a slow network from a linked table?

If so try creating local tables to see if that is where the bottleneck is.

Comment: When the form loads everything should be up-to-date and displayed. What I was referring to is if the items in a row source of the listbox or ComboBox is changed in the underlying table after the form is opened then these changes will not automatically refresh.

It may well be that there is a large Recordset being loaded up which is affecting the memory. If so is it possible to further limit the number of rows perhaps by using a drill down approach with a different ComboBox or listbox.

This would explain why it's only happening sometimes on specific computers.

Comment: The backend tables are located on a network share and every user has his own copy of the frontend locally on his computer. But our network is pretty fast and stable, so I would rule that out. Also when I am developing, I only use local copies of the DB and FrontEnd, and it sometimes (but very rarely) also happened to me. I also don't think it has to do with large recordsets, as sometimes the recordset is only 2-3 records and is still not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing something special with that recordset in your VBA code? If you are just running static SQL like that, you can just set the rowsource type to Table/Query and paste `SELECT ID, Name FROM Users WHERE ID <> 1` into the RowSource property-- it doesn't have to be the name of a saved query.

Comment: Many SQL queries I use are static, and those work without problems. But for some I need to insert values that I get through VBA (for example: just show records that are assigned to the user using the database. I set his ID in a global variable on startup of the application and then insert his ID in the WHERE clauses. Is there maybe some way to use global VBA variables in the RowSource property?)

Comment: You can enter the temporary variables  directly into the row source SQL in the property sheet. For example:

SELECT ID, Name from Users WHERE ID = Application.TempVars![UserID];

Comment: Queries can call any function defined as public in a standard module. I recommend using http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0008.htm to properly get the windows login name. Then you can write `=fOSUserName()` in a query's criteria row or WHERE UserID=fOSUserName() in a where clause.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access there is no event that specifically occurs after everything has loaded. In my case I was having a similar issue with a listbox control returning null query because the query referenced one of my forms source fields that had not completely loaded yet. There is one event that will help us though, the Form_Timer() event.

Please note, you need to **change your forms Timer Interval property** to a value (500 ms should do). If you leave it at 0 it will not run. Pro-tip, set the timer delay in design view.

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()

    'Use 0 for TimeInterval so that it only runs the event once. 
    'Don't forget to set your Timer Interval property on your form. 

    Me.TimerInterval = 0
    Me.listAddresses.Requery
    Debug.Print "Timer Ran"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a different and more preferred solution to my problem.

Here I'm setting a list Box's row source to a query. Both queries accomplish the same thing on my form. The first query is reusable, but at the cost of not refreshing and generally being buggy.

The second query is specific to my frmJobView, but loads when the form loads and does not bug out or require additional timer/refresh code.

Only focus on the very last section of each WHERE clause.

**Screen.ActiveForm!.[Job_ID]** - Can be used on any form, but will not load with form / needs refresh. See my other answer about refresh if you absolutely must have this.

**[Forms]![frmJobView].[Job_ID]** - Only works on frmJobView, but loads with the form.

```
//This SQL statement will require a refresh if you set it to a listbox
    SELECT [tblJobAddresses].ID, 
    FROM tblJobAddresses
    WHERE [tblJobAddresses].Job_ID=Screen.ActiveForm![Job_ID];

//This SQL statement will not require a refresh after loading the form.
    SELECT *
    FROM tblJobContacts
    WHERE [tblJobContacts].Job_ID=[Forms]![frmJobView].[Job_ID];
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything to fix this issue in Access 2010, but the ListBox remained blank on startup.

Finally in a fit of desperation I tried adding this as the very first item in the Form Load:

Me.Dirty = False

It works!  I don't care how or why but now my ListBox populates itself at startup. Previously it refused to display anything until an explicit event happened, like re-selecting the item in the Combo Box.